# keeping up to date with service packs and updates

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, updates, service-pack

Does Microsoft or anyone provide an email update or feed that will notify me when there is a service pack or important update available?  I was recently put in charge of a group of servers and come to find out, majority are missing service packs and updates.  I just want to make sure that when the next update or service pack comes out, I will know about it and be ready for it.

Filehippo is cool, but i just want to know about Microsoft.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Server 2008 has a built in feature to control updates and can roll them out to clients across your network.

Take a look at [Windows Server Update Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/bb332157)

Security Alert feeds here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/dd252948

Office and Related updates feed here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/office/ee748587

Comment: WSUS is a good way to go, I've used it a bit and it has some good reporting ability for the machines it is in charge of.  You can see if certain updates fail, and on which machines.

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft Security Bulletin Advance Notification](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/advance)

[Then there is Patch Tuesday](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_Tuesday)

.